# Shouldn’t the elements of the row space of an $m\times n$ matrix have to structurally be rows, i.e., $1\times n$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Apologize in advance if this seems a bit nit picky or even trivial but this has been bugging me.

I realize that defining the row space of a matrix as the span of its rows is perfectly adequate for the purposes of row reduction, determining rank, bases of the row space and other matrix manipulations. Works just fine.

Providing a more rigorous definition in terms of an underlying *linear transformation represented by the matrix in a pair of bases*, however, is less straightforward than the column space. The column space is simply the span of the columns of the matrix which correspond to vectors in the codomain of the transformation represented as column vectors in a codomain basis.

My understanding is that if one is being rigorous (some may say anal-retentive) matrix rows, although often casually referred to as “row vectors”, don’t directly correspond to or represent vectors in a transformation’s domain or codomain. They are more precisely transformation matrices themselves, $1\times n$ matrices which return a scalar when applied to an $n$-row column vector, i.e., linear functionals.

I have seen two formal definitions of a row space of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, where $M_n^m$ is the set of all $m\times n$ matrices.

1. The first is most analogous to the common definition of the column space as
   $$C(A)=\{AX : X\in M^n_1\}$$ where $$X=\begin{pmatrix}x^1\\\vdots\\x^n\end{pmatrix}$$ The row space is defined by flipping the product and adjusting the dimension of variable appropriately. $$R(A)=\{YA : Y\in M_m^1\}$$ where $$Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1&\cdots&y_m\end{pmatrix}$$This is in fact the span of the rows of $A$ consisting of linear combinations with coefficients $(y_1,…,y_m)$ as the above initial informal definition requires.
2. The more common formal definition, at least in all of the textbooks and lecture notes I have read, is that the row space is just the column space of the transpose of $A$.

$$R(A)=C(A^T)=\{A^{T}X : X\in M^m_1\}$$

But #1 and 2 are the same only down to a transpose. The row space elements in #1 are $1\times n$ matrices (i.e., rows) while the row space elements in #2 are $n\times 1$ matrices (i.e., columns). Seems like the elements of a row space should be rows in which case the row space would be the set of *transposes* of the column space of $A$ and the proper form of #2 would be

$$R(A)=\{X^T : X\in C(A^T)\}=\{(A^{T}X)^T : X\in M^m_1\}$$

which is exactly equivalent to #1 since

$$(A^{T}X)^T=X^{T}(A^T)^T=YA$$

where
$$Y=X^T\in M_m^1$$

Again, maybe I am being nitpicky and this is much ado about nothing, but it bothers me that everyone seems to refer to two things as the same when they are really transposes of each other. Am I missing something?

Comment: The vectors are being identified as vectors, and so there is no such thing as a row or column vector. If you are identifying them as linear maps, then there would be a difference.

Comment: These are equivalent definitions, the transpose is actually an isomorphism of vector space (between column vectors and rows vectors) so what you're looking at is exactly the same thing up to a canonical isomorphism. However I believe that you should not try to focus so much on the "column space", just think of it as the image of the linear transformation induced by your matrix. Same for row space, it is the image of the transpose of your linear transformation, which is exactly the linear transformation associated to the transpose of your matrix. I don't know how much you know of duality...

Comment: @AndrewZhang I disagree, $\mathbb{K}^n$ has a very particular structure that allows a canonical isomorphism with its dual. The column or row notation actually is important to show the nature of the object. But I also agree with the fact that thinking of vector spaces would just be less confusing (maybe I did not get your point)

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace -- I think that is what he meant by "linear maps" vs "vectors"

Comment: @User5678 ok thank you, I think that the vectors identified as vectors lost me haha

Comment: @AndrewZhang I understand that this is an non issue if we stick to linear maps and their images. Distinguishing between rows and columns does seem important when dealing with their matrix representation since we define matrix products in a specific order and way.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Thanks and agree that best to focus on the underlying transformations but a lot of linear algebra happens in the world of matrix representation of linear transformations where the distinction between rows and columns does matter because of the conventions of matrix algebra we have selected. In this paradigm it seems that the two defintions are different (down to a transpose) and that it is wrong to say that the row space of a matrix is the column space of its transpose. I do know a bit re: duality & dual spaces of vector space, but not much depth. Realize it applies here.

Comment: Since the isomorphism between both is canonical, it's not wrong to me, but you could just describe it as $R(A) = C(A^T)^T$ if you wish to have the exact setting.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Thanks. Will read to refresh on canonical isomorphisms but glad that I can move on now that you have confirmed that I am not missing something and the precise description is as you have above. Cheers!

Comment: Identify the column space with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the row space with $(\mathbb{R}^m)^*$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$).

Comment: @copper.hat Using dual spaces to highlight the distinction seems like a good idea but isn’t $\mathbb{R}^n$ self dual. If so how does your suggestion really work in a distinguishing the row and column space of, for example, a square matrix if $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*=\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @user175324 they are isomorphic not equal. It is the distinction you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Matrices are also vectors. Column vectors are just $n \times 1$ matrices.

The space of $1 \times m$ matrices is also a vector space, as is the space of $n \times m$ matrices.

So, if you take the span of rows or the columns as the basis of a space, you still end up with a vector space.

The "linear functional" convention is due to the convention that the argument is to the right of a function, not the left (i.e., it's $f(x)$ not $(x)f$), but there isn't anything special about columns vs rows except by convention.

Comment: I realize that matrices are vectors in the mn-dimensional vector space of m x n matrices but this not the same as the n-dimensional domain and  m-dimensional codomain vector spaces of a linear transformation underlying and represented by an m x n matrix, right? Acknowledging that all of these are vector spaces, am I right in objecting to the definition of the row space of an m x n matrix (a vector space of n x 1 matrices) as the column space of its transpose (a vector space if 1 x n matrices). They are different vector spaces containing different shapes matrices.

Comment: Said differently, the vector space of 2 x 3 matrices is not the same as the vector space of 3 x 2 matrices, even though they are both six dimensional and have one-to-one corresponded (the transpose function)

Comment: Correct, its not. But I think the _definition_ of the row space of an $nxm$ matrix is the vector space spanned by the rows viewed as elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RowSpace.html -- so this might be a matter of definition vs taking it literally as the space spanned by the $1\times m$ row vectors.

Comment: *correspondence

Comment: Thanks. I saw the Wolfram  definition and certainly if one treats rows and columns as identical to n-tuples (not just isomorphic to) as they and others do then there is no real distinction. To me they seem a bit loose with their language, admittedly without any real practical consequence. Khan Academy is more direct. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/matrix-transpose/v/linear-algebra-rowspace-and-left-nullspace. He follows an example by saying straight up that “…the columnspace of the transpose of any matrix, IS called the rowspace of A”.

Comment: @user175324 — fair. It’s true that row vectors (also called covectors) multiply on the left not the right and are not identical. Taken literally the space of $1xn$ row vectors isn’t the same as the space of $nx1$ column vectors